# Real Analysis - Prove the sequence converges to f'(c)

Tags: real-analysis

I have this one question  in which,
suppose that f is defined on an open interval I and that f is differentiable at point c within interval I.

Prove that

$$n\big(f(c+1/n)-f(c)\big)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}f'(c).$$

I'm mainly stuck on how to start it or if there's any identity I need to use or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$n\big(f(c+1/n)-f(c)\big)=\frac{f(c+1/n)-f(c)}{1/n}.$$ How does this compare to the definition for derivatives?

Comment: Isn't this the definition of derivative with H approaching 1/n?

Comment: @xCanaan: If you think of $n\to\infty$, then $1/n\to0$. Usually we think about $h\to0$, so here is just a speicifc sequence tending to $0$ as opposed to an arbitrary sequence (from the definition of derivative).

Comment: Oh! That makes sense since we started with a sequence with n instead of h(for functions), we have to use that theorem that allows us to use sequences for functions.

Comment: @xCanaan: I think you've got it now!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$n \left( f(c + \frac1n) - f(c) \right) = \frac{f(c + \frac1n) - f(c)}{\frac1n}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{n} =0$$ and by definition of the derivative $$f^\prime(c)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$

So what happens if you replace $h$ by $\frac{1}{n}$?